# Google Picker Search only inside parent folder

Tags: google-picker

I am using `setParent()` to show a particular folder only in `Google picker` but searching lists all the files and folders. I want search results `restricted to parent folder`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no way to do this with the picker API. One hack is to filter for starred files but that is usually not helpful because you probably just want to set one directory/folder to search inside.

In the end I had to use the Google Drive API instead and create my own interface

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js" integrity="sha512-RNLkV3d+aLtfcpEyFG8jRbnWHxUqVZozacROI4J2F1sTaDqo1dPQYs01OMi1t1w9Y2FdbSCDSQ2ZVdAC8bzgAg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: rgb(221, 238, 232);">

    <div style="max-width: 1100px; margin: auto;" class="conainer  mt-5">

        <div class="row text-center mt-5">
            <div class="col-10 ms-5">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <input type="search" class="form-control me-2" id="search_input" oninput="search(event)" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" oninput="search(event)">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row text-center mt-5 ">
            <div class="col-10 ms-5" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 5px;">
                <template type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="documentsTemplate">
                    <div class="row mt-2 mb-2">
                        {{#if documents.length}}
                            {{#each documents}}
                            <div class="col-2 mt-2">
                                <div style="height: 200px; width:150px; background-color: white; border-radius: 5px; border: solid 1px; border-color: lightblue;">
                                    <img style="height: 150px; width:150px;" src="{{thumbnailLink}}" />
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                                    <a href="#">{{name}}</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {{/each}}
                        {{else}}
                            <div style="height: 200px; width:100%; background-color: white; text-align: center; font-size: 2vw; margin: 0 auto;">
                                No Results
                            </div>
                        {{/if}}
                    </div>
                </template>
                <div id="documentsList"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>    
    <!-- <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
//script.js
//import { google_client_id } from "./utils/configs.js"
// get this from 'APIs and Services'>credentials>Oauth app
const google_client_id=XXXXX

(function() {

          // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
          function onApiLoad() {
            gapi.load('auth2', onAuthApiLoad);
            gapi.load('picker', onPickerApiLoad);
          }
        

    globalThis.search = (event) => {

        clearTimeout(globalThis.searchTimeout);

        globalThis.searchTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            getTemplateFolder()
                .then(searchFiles)
        }, 1000)

    }

    document.getElementById('search_input').addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
        var key = event.key || event.keyCode;
        if (key === 13) {
          // Cancel the default action, if needed
          event.preventDefault();
          search(event);
        }
    });


    gapi.load('client:auth2', (aa) => {
        gapi.client.init({
                client_id: google_client_id,
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"],
            })
            .then(checkSession)
            .then(function() {
                return getTemplateFolder();
            })
            .then(function(folder) {
                return getFiles(folder);
            });
    });

    function checkSession() {
        if (!gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()) {
            return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
        }
    }

    function getTemplateFolder() {
        return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = 'XXXXXX' and trashed = false",
            pageSize: 10,
            fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response.result.files[0];
        });
    }

    function getFiles(templateFolder) {
        return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            q: `'${templateFolder.id}' in parents and trashed = false`,
            pageSize: 10,
            fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, thumbnailLink)',
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector("#documentsTemplate").innerHTML);
            document.querySelector("#documentsList").innerHTML = template({ documents: response.result.files });

            return response.result.files;
        });
    }

    function searchFiles(templateFolder) {
        return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            q: `'${templateFolder.id}' in parents and fullText contains '${document.getElementById("search_input").value}' and trashed = false`,
            pageSize: 10,
            fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, thumbnailLink)',
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector("#documentsTemplate").innerHTML);
            document.querySelector("#documentsList").innerHTML = template({ documents: response.result.files });

            return response.result.files;
        });
    }
})();
```

Make sure to add the google_client_id and the directory name you want to filter by.