# Navigation not possible when a parent is set in Google API picker (docsView)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker, google-drive-picker

I'm a bit stuck with the Google API and the Drive file picker.

I want the Drive file picker to open at a given location (folder) in Drive, but users should also be able to navigate outside that location anywhere else to select a file from any other location.

Using `setParent()` on the `DocsView` object, the picker does open with that "starting" folder.
However, the navigation pane also disappears and it's not possible to get anywhere in the Drive (unless doing a search, but that's not obvious...).

For example when there is **NO** `setParent()` this what I got, *after going inside the "starting" folder* --> there is a navigation pane under the search area:
[image]

But if I set a parent (using `setParent()`), then I have no more navigation pane, and I need it...
[image]

This is how I create the builder:

```
const docsView = new google.picker.DocsView();
docsView.setMimeTypes("application/vnd.google-apps.folder" + ((this.showFolderOnly) ? "" : ",application/aspyre"));
if(this.appStore.initFolder != undefined){
    docsView.setParent(this.appStore.initFolder.toString());
}
const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
    .addView(docsView)
    .disableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
    .disableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
    .setLocale(useStore().appLang)
    .setOAuthToken(this.oauthToken)
    .setDeveloperKey(this.devKey)
    .setCallback(this.pickerCallback)
    .build();
picker.setVisible(true);
```

Thanks a lot for your help, maybe I've missed something out the document but frankly... I don't know what...

Pierre

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to do this with the Google Picker API, you can submit a feature idea through [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106), this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967332/google-picker-search-only-inside-parent-folder) is related to your question and the only workaround was creating their own interface and used the Drive API instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and the links. For the moment, I've just made 2 docviews in the picker so that users can easily get to their drive. It's not the best but it works. I think that was what was done in that other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391991/is-it-possible-to-upload-to-root-of-sub-folders-with-google-picker) which at first I didn't understand.